# Check if Object is nil and needed attribute is nil or empty

Tags: ruby

I am looking for "elegant" way to check if given object is nil and it's attribute is nil or empty. At the moment I have this check

```
response = foo.call() # some service call, no http code given :)
raise StandardError, "Response is not valid" if response.nil? || response['data'].nil? || reponse['data'].emtpy?
```

Is there more elegant way to do this, and avoid triple OR check? Wrap in `begin/catch` is not elegant way in case somebody would suggest that.

Comment: Why are you raising `Exception` instead of `StandardError`?

Comment: It was just an example, in any case good point I will correct it.

Comment: I didn't mean to nitpick, it's just that `rescue`ing from `Exception` will also rescue `Interrupt`s, `SyntaxError`s and other system exceptions. I've seen that hide some nasty bugs.

Comment: In this case, it's reasonable to omit `StandardError` and simply use the implicit form of `raise "some message"` (which will raise `RuntimeError`), but if being explicit, `StandardError` is best, I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
data = response.try(:[], 'data')
raise Exception, "Response is not valid" if data.nil? || data.empty?
```

As @ksol correctly mentions in the comments, `try` helper comes from ActiveSupport. But it is not difficult at all to re-implement.

```
class Object
  def try method, *args
    if respond_to? method
      send method, *args
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  def hello name
    "hello #{name}"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.try(:bar) # => nil
f.try(:hello, 'world') # => "hello world"
nil.try(:wat) # => nil
```

### Alternatives

Here's [Object#andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) if you don't want to drag along the entire activesupport and don't feel like writing code that's already written.

```
data = response.andand['data']
raise Exception, "Response is not valid" if data.nil? || data.empty?
```

Comment: Do note that `try` is not standard ruby and comes with ActiveSupport.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that. But it's trivial to implement.

Answer (score 3):

If this is within Rails, you can do:

```
raise "Response is not valid" unless response && response['data'].present?
```

Outside of Rails, I'm not sure you can do too much better than your original line. Another variation could be:

```
raise "Response is not valid" unless response && response['data'] && !response['data'].empty?
```

Obviously this last line is not much different than yours.

Comment: Your last line is exactly the same as mine.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. Didn't see your response before I started writing mine. Great minds? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
unless response && response['data'] && !response['data'].empty?
```